# Image segmentation steps to find the copy paste region in java

Tags: java, image-processing, copy-paste

I have an image and in that image I copy some part of the image and pasted that part in other part of the image. Now I have to detect the edge of the copy pasted part in that image. The edge should be highlighted using red/yellow color in java.

Just help me. I want how to proceed.

I have this idea of doing it. I will read the image into pixels and I will do pixels relation to get which group of pixels are same(the copy paste region will be same as the original region). And I will highlight the edge using the red color. I just want the steps to proceed in program in java. Not want full coding just want the starting steps.